Overlapping IP issue between VPC and VPN

Above architecture diagram has 3 VPCs & 2 site-to-site VPN connections
VPC-A,
VPC-B,
VPC-C (contains shared services)
VPN-A is connected to VPC-A only using transit gateway.
VPN-B is connected to VPC-B only using transit gateway.
There is also two-way connectivity between VPC-A, VPC-C and also between VPC-B, VPC-C.
Problem is IP overlap between VPN Gateway A and VPC-C. Both are using CIDR 10.4.0.0/16.
So, how can VPC A diffentiate between VPN Gateway A and VPC-C and have two-way connectivity with both VPN Gateway A and VPC-C?
What should I do resolve IP overlap issue without changing CIDR?

you can not connect if you are having overlapping CIDR.

Overlapping CIDRs are not supported, but there are a few patterns to overcome this, though it would depend on what you're hosting within the VPCs.

Using AWS Private Link to 'hide' your services behind a NLB, and connect to it via VPC Endpoints from another VPC. This traffic doesn't go through the Transit Gateway and uses the AWS Backbone. This is great for producer-consumer type architecture.

Similar concept to Private Link but has a slightly different architecture and use case; AWS VPC Lattice. This is great for service-to-service communication, again via the AWS Backbone.

You could use Private NAT Gateways, but you would need to disable route propagation and use static routing. More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-scenarios.html#private-nat-overlapping-networks

(This option is probably a little complicated). You could deploy a router within a dedicated VPC, and set up an IPSEC tunnel between the Router and the TGW, and the Router and a VGW on VPC C. You would need to publish a unique CIDR block to the TGW from the Router, and perform NAT.


